# Python Selenium how to find element with changing text

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a program that auto-completes questions. But the answers to the questions are choices and they will change every time.
There are four choices and I only want it to click one of them.
This work but the text will change every time: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'The home of a person/ company.')]").click()`
I have tried this: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("choices").click()` and it won't work.
So, I want no matter what the text part is, the program can search and click on it. But only clicking one of the choices.

[Picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFfBZ.png) [with html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJVC2.png)

```
HTML:<p class="choices" xpath="1">The home of a person/ company.</p>
xpath of this://p[contains(text(),'The home of a person/ company.')]
absXpath:/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/label[4]/p[1]
```

Please help.

Comment: So, what exactly problem is here? You don't know how to pass texts to a function that will find element and click on it?

Comment: clicking on the choices with changing text.

Comment: And you know what texts will appear there?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: The answers will change according to the question so I won't be knowing the text that appers

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hcEKrr0.png

Comment: It will need a account to get in the website.

Comment: view-source:https://macao4.i-learner.com.hk/new_interface2019/exercise_new.html?qid=1&aid=17566

Comment: I need a page, not a picture. I'm sure we can use much more effective locators than by text

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bE1RWcy.png

Comment: https://macao.i-learner.com.hk/

Comment: An account is needed to get in.

Comment: I see.. can you provide us a credentials? i hope it's not something payed, I just do not understand this language...

Comment: I only have my personal account and it contains personal information.

Comment: I understand. But without that I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

first check wheather you are using correct xpath because the xpath changes as the position of options are changed. Also, according to your code you can use specific id for this problem because class can be provieded for multiple elements but id is unique.

Comment: But seems like the xpath path is different on every page. And the choices don't have ids. https://i.imgur.com/Yq1EwlM.png

Comment: Is it possible for you to use find_element_by_name

Comment: The names are random on every page. There is a module "re" it has the feature of re.findall("texts (.*?) texts") the .*? can be anything. I am thinking that is there a similar feature that can make the rel xpath //p[contains(text(),'The home of a person/ company.')] to change like this //p[contains(text(),'.*?')]

Answer (score 0):

To click the first option use css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tbtow.exercise_frame>.each_question.mc_question>label:nth-child(1)>p")
```

Check classes spelling by yourself because I typed them from the picture you provided. Also, experiment with `:nth-of-type(1)` instead of `:nth-child(1)`
To change position use `:nth-of-type(2)`, `:nth-of-type(3)` and so on.